# Web scraping a forum

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My concern revolves around how to store the data I'm trying to retrieve data from certain threads of a forum. I want to be able to plot as much information as I want, so I don't want to store everything in a rigid structure; I want to be able to use as much info as I can (timezones more active, timezones more active per user, keywords throughout the years, points throughout posters, etc).

How should I store this? A tree with upper nodes being pages and lower as posts? How do I store that tree in a way it is easy* to read?

* easy as in encapsulated in a format I could export easily to other stuff.

Comment: It’s hilarious that people are downvoting/voting to close this question because of a mere mention of scraping. Scraping in absence of APIs has powered various initiatives perceived as doing common good. Think that answering innocent JavaScript question from another person can enable them to do some evil thing with their app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest to scrape only the posts (why would you ever need the pages?) into JSON, which you can keep in PostgreSQL in a jsonb field—it allows querying your JSON flexibly.

Later you’d write a script, or multiple, that would iterate over posts and do useful stuff like cleaning up the data, normalizing values, aggregating stats, etc.

#### See also

- Someone wrote a post about [PostgreSQL and querying JSON](http://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/)

Comment: With storing the pages I meant tracking posts' pages (i.e. in which pages appear these or those words), not the whole source code of the page.

I was thinking about xml or json before coming here but I wasn't sure it was... the "natural" way of doing it.

Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I’d say go with JSON for sure, if compared with XML. There’s also YAML, but it doesn’t have the fancy support in PostgreSQL, Mongo and others.

Comment: As to encapsulating relationships between pages and posts, I’m still not sure about the idea behind pages. However, let’s say pages ‘contain’ hosts—well, you could just embed a list of contained posts in every page object ({page_id: …, posts: []}), maybe with only a subset of post data depending on the need; you could still keep a separate index of posts e.g. by their ID as well. Sure, a bit of a performance hit, but perhaps not large enough to care.